# SQL Server 2014 server new to JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am new to SQL server.
I would like to ask how can I join these statements? The result should be batman, tim burton to james murrilo.

```
            CREATE TABLE Movie(
                movieId INT NOT NULL,
                movieTitle CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                director CHAR(50) NOT NULL
                PRIMARY KEY (movieId)
            );
            INSERT INTO Movie (movieId, movieTitle, director)VALUES (1, 'Batman', 'Tim Burton');
            INSERT INTO Movie (movieId, movieTitle, director)VALUES (2, 'Spiderman','Sam Raimi');

            CREATE TABLE Reviewer(
                reviewerId INT NOT NULL,
                reviewerName CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (reviewerId)
            );
            INSERT INTO Reviewer (reviewerId, reviewerName) VALUES(1, 'David Carroll');
            INSERT INTO Reviewer (reviewerId, reviewerName) VALUES(2, 'James Murillo');

            CREATE TABLE Movie_Reviewers(
                movieId INT NOT NULL,
                reviewerId INT NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT movieReviewerPK PRIMARY KEY(movieId, reviewerId),
                CONSTRAINT movieFK1 FOREIGN KEY(movieId) REFERENCES Movie,
                CONSTRAINT reviewerFK1 FOREIGN KEY(reviewerId) REFERENCES Reviewer
            );
            INSERT INTO Movie_Reviewers (MovieId, reviewerId) VALUES(1,2);
            INSERT INTO Movie_Reviewers (MovieId, reviewerId) VALUES(2,1);

            SELECT Movie_Reviewers.*, Movie.MovieTitle, Movie.director, Reviewer.reviewerName
                FROM Movie_Reviewers
                JOIN Movie ON Movie.MovieId = Movie_Reviewers.MovieId
                JOIN Reviewer ON Reviewer.reviewerId = Movie_Reviewers.MovieId
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: What statement do you want join? i am sorry i don't get it what you try to achieve. be more specify on your question so we can help you too..

Comment: The expected output should be batman, tim burton to james murrilo. I fixed it now

Comment: Why do you want to "join" `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the last line - Movie_Reviewers.ReviewerID

```
JOIN Reviewer ON Reviewer.reviewerId = Movie_Reviewers.ReviewerId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use where clause and there is a small mistake in your last join  - what I understand from your question you need to get movie id 1 value
using your query you'll get all results for movie

```
SELECT Movie_Reviewers.*, Movie.MovieTitle, Movie.director, Reviewer.reviewerName
                FROM Movie_Reviewers
                JOIN Movie ON Movie.MovieId = Movie_Reviewers.MovieId
                JOIN Reviewer ON Reviewer.reviewerId = Movie_Reviewers.reviewerId
where Movie.MovieId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Join with valid Primary key and Foreign key Relationship,

```
        SELECT Movie_Reviewers.*, Movie.MovieTitle, Movie.director, Reviewer.reviewerName
            FROM Movie_Reviewers
            JOIN Movie ON Movie.MovieId = Movie_Reviewers.MovieId
            JOIN Reviewer ON Reviewer.reviewerId = Movie_Reviewers.reviewerId
```